# Named tuples - Swift - How to use

Tags: swift, tuples

This is my error:
[image: My Error]
This is my function in Module A:

```
func current_street(){
   var l = theCoreLocationController?.ltuple //lat,long
   let g = GeocodeObject(lat: l.lat, long: l.long, userstate: USER_STATE)
}
```

This is `CoreLocationController` class in Module B:

```
public class CoreLocationController : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    public var ltuple: (lat:Double, long:Double)?;
    ...
```

And this is the declaration for `theCoreLocationController` in Module C:

```
var theCoreLocationController: CoreLocationController?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exercise care on optionals.  Your `ltuple` returns an optional and your `theCoreLocationController` is also an optional.

Use:

```
func current_street(){
   let l = theCoreLocationController?.ltuple {
     let g = GeocodeObject(lat: l.lat, long: l.long, userstate: USER_STATE)
     // ...
   }
}
```

`l` will be bound to a tuple if and only if `theCoreLocationController` is not `nil` and if `ltuple` is not `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ltuple` is an optional.  To achieve what you want you should unwrap it.  E.g.

```
func current_street(){
   if let l = theCoreLocationController?.ltuple //lat,long {
     let g = GeocodeObject(lat: l.lat, long: l.long, userstate: USER_STATE)
     // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: It gives me `CoreLocationController? does not have a member named ltuple`

Comment: Ah, your `theCoreLocationController ` an optional too.  Then the line should look like:

    `if let l = theCoreLocationController?.ltuple`

BTW, if `theCoreLocationController` is something that is for sure always there, then you might want to declare it like `var theCoreLocationController: CoreLocationController!`